# Storing a reference to a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class which manages a `Stream`:

```
class MyStreamManager {
    private Stream<Object> currentStream = null;

    boolean hasMoreData() {
        //code here to assert currentStream is null

        final Optional<Stream<Object>> maybeAStream = somethingWhichMightProvideAStream.getNextStream();

        currentStream = maybeAStream.orElse(null);

        return currentStream != null;
    }

    @MustBeClosed
    Stream<Object> getCurrentStream() { return currentStream; }

    void finish() {
        currentStream.close();
        currentStream = null;
    }
}
```

Which is used in the following style:

```
while (myStreamManager.hasMoreData()) {
  try {
       myStreamManager.getCurrentStream().map(...).filter(...); //etc
  } finally {
       myStreamManager.finish();
  }
}
```

Is storing a reference to a Stream like this bad practice? While this works, it definitely doesn't feel right, and ErrorProne is flagging it (hence the `@MustBeClosed` annotation).

`MyStreamManager` is a Spring `@Bean` but is only used by one thread (this is running in a batch).

I can think of two different approaches which are probably better:

- instantiate `MyStreamManager` and wrap it in a `try-with-resources`, delegating the `close()` call to the `Stream`
- use the `Spliterators` class to create a `Spliterator` that delegates to many `Stream`s?

Comment: A stream once closed cannot be reused. Is that what `@MustBeClosed` means?

Comment: The @MustBeClosed is an annotation used by ErrorProne to 'pass the buck', allowing a method to return a Stream and compell the calling class to close the Stream.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for codereview.se since your code is working. At first glance I already see 3 bad smells: 1. `MyStreamManager` which is a bean, actually holds state; 2. It's preferable to return an empty `Stream` than wrapping it into an `Optional`; 3. `hasMoreData()` operates via side-effects, contrary to what it's name seems to imply. From the provided code it isn't clear why you would need `MyStreamManager` at all though.

Comment: I don't think that it's unreasonable to require callers of `getCurrentStream()` to do the closing: after all, you're reassigning the field in `hasMoreData`, so there is no guarantee that `finish()` will actually close it. You only do because you use it in this (rather awkward looking) while/try/finally; but the compiler can't know that's how you will use it

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice at all, just use your stream as you wish. However, this doesn't mean that there aren't better approaches...

Comment: Probably it's just me, but this all smells a bit of an xy problem type question

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it's as much the fact you're storing a `Stream` per se that makes this feel awkward, but rather that you've got [sequential coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling).

You *have to* call `hasMoreData`; then `getCurrentStream()`; then `finish()`. If you're only using the class in a limited number of places, you will probably be able to get it right in all of those; but every place you use it is a new opportunity to use it incorrectly.

I would say that your manager class is actually just making things harder for yourself.

```
for (Optional<Stream<Object>> opt = somethingWhichMightProvideAStream.getNextStream();
     opt.isPresent();
     opt = somethingWhichMightProvideAStream.getNextStream()) {
  try (Stream<Object> stream = opt.get()) {  // try-with-resources auto-closes the stream
    stream.map(...).filter(...); //etc
  }
}
```

or:

```
Optional<Stream<Object>> opt;
while ((opt = somethingWhichMightProvideAStream.getNextStream()).isPresent()) {
  try (Stream<Object> stream = opt.get()) {
    stream.map(...).filter(...); //etc
  }
}
```

The loop declarations in either case are not especially pretty; but this is way shorter (roughly as long as the while/try/finally loop you already have), and harder to use wrong, I think.

(Admittedly, you've still got sequential coupling here: you have to remember to close the stream returned in the optional. Sigh.)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing imperative *(while loop, try-finally)* and declarative *(streams)* code together doesn't seem right.
If all of these opeartions are synchronous I guess it could be done in one pipeline (without MyStreamManager at all).

I think that you could think of focusing on moving some logic to object containing method `somethingWhichMightProvideAStream` because mixing imperative iterator pattern with stream API doesn't look like idiomatic. For example it can return `List` (or even better a `Stream`!) of `Streams` instead of `Optional`

Think twice if you really need to close this stream. From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> Streams have a `BaseStream.close()` method and implement `AutoCloseable`, but nearly all stream instances do not actually need to be closed after use. Generally, only streams whose source is an IO channel (such as those returned by `Files.lines(Path, Charset))` will require closing.